# wp multilang plugin. how to set the language in php

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there an option in the wp multilang plugin to set the language for wp_insert_post? And how can this be done?

```
    $post_data = array(
        'post_title'    => $st_title,
        'post_name' => $st_name,
        'post_content'  =>  $st_text,       
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'comment_status' => 'closed'
        
    );
```

Comment: "wp multilang plugin" meaning, WPML? https://www.sumitgupta.net/how-to-programmatically-add-multi-language-post-in-wordpress-and-wpml/

Comment: @CBroe here is this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multilang/#developers , the documentation says that it takes the 'lang' parameter to create a record, but for some reason it doesn't work for me

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are referring to. Perhaps this stores the language as post meta data or something, then you would have to create _that_.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this questions and the plugin [WP Multilang](https://github.com/VaLeXaR/wp-multilang) is quite outdated as the last update of the owner was 4 years ago. Nevertheless, wordpress.org states out [10.000+ active installations](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multilang). So, if somebody came along here looking for an answer, that's the way how it's done:

The language for inserting or updating a post isn't put with the post data, but is saved as a fixed user meta in the database ([see the code here](https://github.com/g4rf/wp-multilang/blob/19248e25a14acd9fcb14c871255eb9dca9cbf7f2/includes/admin/class-wpm-admin.php#L61)). Every time, the language is changed, the user meta is updated. To do so by code, just override the setting. **As I didn't checked this in every way, test it carefully for your use case!**

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
$lang = 'de'; // alter language for your needs
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'edit_lang', $lang );
```

Be careful, as you *globally* change the edit language for every post with this setting. That is by design in WP Multilang and can't be changed.

**UPDATE**

Writing the lines above yesterday as a first approach, I digged deeper into it. The solution **won't work** for `wp_insert_post` and `wp_update_post`, as both of them won't invoke all the necessary filters and actions from WP Multilang to translate the strings. But with the help of the WP Multilang functions we can build our own multilingual strings and insert them into `post_title`, `post_content`, and `post_excerpt`.

```
$localize_array = [
    'en' => 'Hello World!',
    'de' => 'Hallo Welt!'
];

$post_content = wpm_ml_array_to_string($localize_array);
```

`$post_content` can now be used in the `$post_data` array.

To get **existing translations** and **add a new one**, use `wpm_translate_string()` as follows:

```
$post = get_post($postId);
$localize_array = [
    'en' => wpm_translate_string($post->post_content, 'en'),
    'de' => 'Deutsche Übersetzung des Beitragstextes.'
];
$fully_translated_post_content = wpm_ml_array_to_string($localize_array));
```